# How ASM checks maximum stack size when duplicating operand stack (DUP_X1 and DUP operands)

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation

I am trying to record instance level (or class level ) object initialization or object assignments through bytecode manipulation (using [`ASM framework`](http://asm.ow2.org/) )

Something like this :

This is the class where I am declaring some instance variables :

```
class DeclarationTestClass1{

    /** Assume This Class has some public instance variables **/
    private MultipleDeclarationTestClass multiClass = null;
    private List<String> arrayList1_String = null;
    public static Hashtable<Integer,Integer> staticHashTable = null;


    public List<String> getArrayList1_String() {
        return arrayList1_String;
    }

    public void setArrayList1_String(List<String> arrayList1_String) {
        this.arrayList1_String = arrayList1_String;
    }
}
```

Now, I want to do :

```
DeclarationTestClass1 object1 = new DeclarationTestClass1();
MultipleDeclarationTestClass object1 .object1_innerObject = new MultipleDeclarationTestClass();

RecordingClass.recordingMethod(object1.arrayList1_String = new ArrayList<String>());
RecordingClass.recordingMethod(object1 .object1_innerObject.someMap = new HashMap<String,String>());
```

Now when I see the output of the desired class using ASMifier , I can see that before the  actual `putfield` is called , there is one `DUP_X1` getting called.

Now , my understanding is that as the instance level object is referred through another object (i.e : `object1.arrayList1_String = new ArrayList<String>()` , second word of the stack holds the object through which it is referred (i.e `object1` ).
Please correct me if I am wrong.

But , what I can not understand , in the second scenario , when the instance level object is reffered through another extra object (i.e: `object1 .object1_innerObject.someMap = new HashMap<String,String>()`) , it has another extra object in the stack , right ?

So my questions are :

1) Why in the second scenario also , `DUP_X1` is called ?

2) I am using `COMPUTE_MAXS` flag in asm , by dint of which asm calculates the max stack size for me . So , will this duplicating have any impact if I do not override `visitMaxs` method in `MethodVisitor`.

Any help in this regard , is much much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Antimony has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24062615/2711488), it doesn’t matter to the stack size whether you have code of the form `x.y = foo` or `x.y.z.a.b.c = foo`.

For each node of the chain the `getfield` instruction will pop the field owner instance from the stack and push the field value onto the stack (which will become the owner for the next node).

So the only interesting part is the `putfield`. It will pop *two* values from the stack, the field owner and the new value. Since you are using an expression of the form `method(x.y=foo)` you need the value a second time, for passing it to the method.

So a kind of `dup` is required, but since the follow-up `putfield` will consume two items, the copy of the value must be pushed down below the field owner:

```
dup_x1:       …, owner, value]        → …, value, owner, value]
putfield:     …, value, owner, value] → …, value]
invokestatic: …, value]               → …]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But , can you please clarify the `asm` part of the question ?

Comment: It’s not clear how you are using the `MethodWriter`. The `visitMax` method must be called to trigger the (re)calculation of the `maxStack` and `maxLocals`, but if you are using a `GeneratorAdapter` for modifying the code you don’t need to override `visitMaxs` as the `GeneratorAdapter` will do the right thing for you.

Comment: No , I am not using `GeneratorAdatper`. But , I am using `COMPUTE_MAXS` flag , which according to `asm` documentation is : `Flag to automatically compute the maximum stack size and the maximum number of local variables of methods. If this flag is set, then the arguments of the visitMaxs method of the MethodVisitor returned by the visitMethod method will be ignored, and computed automatically from the signature and the bytecode of each method.`

Comment: Then what is your question?

Comment: I just wanted to be reaffirm whether I am correct . Never mind , that was really stupid from my end. 

Thanks a lot again for your explanation .

( Just a request : if you find my question valid , can you please upvote it )

Answer (score 1):

You actually wouldn't have anything extra on the stack in the case of 2 indirections over 1, because only the last object is needed for the assignment. Think about it.

```
object1.object1_innerObject.someMap = new HashMap<String,String>())
```

In this code, you evaluate `object1.object1_innerObject` (call it `t1`), then `new HashMap<String,String>()` (call it `t2`), and finally the assignment is performed, `t1.someMap = t2`.

Equivalent bytecode would be (assuming object1 is in local variable slot 1)

```
aload_1
getfield object1type object1_innnerObject innerobjecttype
new HashMap
dup
invokespecial java/util/HashMap <init> ()V
setfield innerobjecttype someMap java/util/HashMap
```

You have a maximum of 3 items on the stack, but that's the same as if you were only doing `object1.someMap`.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the clear and concise answer. Now , I have just one query left. If I do not define max stack size ( by overriding `visitMaxs` and using `COMPUTE_MAXS` flag in `ClassWriter` ) , will this alteration of stack size create any issue ?